# Setting default values for Popup menu

Tags: python, popup, blender

Let's say I have this script pop-up menu with one variable (mine is more complex but simplified for clarity)

```python
import bpy
from bpy.props import *

class DialogOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.dialog_operator"
    bl_label = "Test"

    defValue = bpy.context.active_object.scale[1]

    propertyScale = IntProperty(
                    name = "Scale",
                    default = defValue)

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

bpy.utils.register_class(DialogOperator)
bpy.ops.object.dialog_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

And let's say that I have two Cubes with different scale value and every time I call this pop-up menu I want to scale values of current selected cube be my Default value.

This script above doesn't work, It works when you run it through "Run Script" button but after that if you press "space" and find script there it won't adjust default value according to current active object.

Is there any way how to do this? I think It should be pretty easy but I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I searched web and find this about invoke function ([from here](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_57_release/bpy.types.Operator.html))

`Operator.invoke` is used to initialize the operator from the context at the moment the operator is called. `invoke()` is typically used to assign properties which are then used by `execute()`. Some operators don't have an `execute()` function, removing the ability to be repeated from a script or macro.
This example shows how to define an operator which gets mouse input to execute a function and that this operator can be invoked or executed from the Python API.
Also notice this operator defines its own properties, these are different to typical class properties because blender registers them with the operator, to use as arguments when called, saved for operator undo/redo and automatically added into the user interface.

Code:

```python
import bpy
class SimpleMouseOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """ This operator shows the mouse location,
        this string is used for the tooltip and API docs
    """
    bl_idname = "wm.mouse_position"
    bl_label = "Invoke Mouse Operator"

    x = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    y = bpy.props.IntProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        # rather then printing, use the report function,
        # this way the messag appiers in the header,
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Mouse coords are %d %d" % (self.x, self.y))
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.x = event.mouse_x
        self.y = event.mouse_y
        return self.execute(context)

bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleMouseOperator)

# Test call to the newly defined operator.
# Here we call the operator and invoke it, meaning that the settings are taken
# from the mouse.
bpy.ops.wm.mouse_position('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

# Another test call, this time call execute() directly with pre-defined settings. 
bpy.ops.wm.mouse_position('EXEC_DEFAULT', x=20, y=66)
```

This should explain everything for everyone who have a similiar problem.